# Remove long running animation when page disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

In my view controller, I have a infinitely running UIView animation (resume itself when it stops at certain point).

When I push to other view controller, I want this animation to stop running. I am trying to insert some code in the `view willdisappear` method, but did not find a good way to cancel the UIView's Animation.

I am wondering what's the common practice to deal with such animation + page navigation scenario?

Thanks

Comment: How is the animation running infinitely; are you setting UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat or using recursion or ...?  Is this in a UIView animation block?  Post some code?

Comment: Post the code about how you cancel the UIView's animation in `viewWillDisappear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
}
```

If you don't have some way to communicate with the view's animation, you can remove all animations from the views layer instead.